# mysql: what data model I use for making combination of salts

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-normalization

I have a Salts table given below which have long list of salts:

```
**Salts**:
------------------------
| ID | NAME             |
-------------------------
| 1  | Paracetamol      |
-------------------------
| 2  | Aceclofenac      |
-------------------------
| 3  | Serratiopeptidase|
-------------------------
| 4  | Tizanidine       |
-------------------------
```

also I have table of Unit

**Units**:

```
--------------
| ID | NAME  |
--------------
| 1  | mg    |
-------------
| 2  | gm    |
-------------
| 3  | mcg   |
-------------
```

Now I want to create combination of these salts using unit and quantity, every combination should be unique, example of combinations are:

```
Paracetamol [300 mg]
Paracetamol [200 mg]
```

(in above example **Paracetamol -> is Salt Name**, **200 -> is the quantity of the salt** and **mg -> is the unit of the salt**),
*Other Example of combination:*

```
Paracetamol [200 mcg]
Aceclofenac [50 mcg] + Paracetamol [250 mg]
Aceclofenac [50 mcg] + Paracetamol [250 mcg]
Aceclofenac [100 mg] + Paracetamol [500 mg] + Serratiopeptidase [15 mg] + Tizanidine [2 mg]
```

in above list all the combination are unique and can't be repeated.
So my question is what should be best data model(schema) to store combinations so that it will be unique and also database remain normalized.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table having column

```
salt_name varchar(100),
quantity int,
unit varchar(20)
```

For this table you can combile these 3 columns as unique key

Comment: but in this method salt and unit name will become redundant